# Subgroups and corresponding fixed fields of Galois group of primitive 24th root of unity.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, primitive-roots

I have been asked to determine the lattice of subgroups of $G=\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $24^{th}$ root of unity. I am then asked to determine their corresponding fixed fields.

We know that the automorphisms of a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity $\alpha$ are given by $a^k$ such that $k$ and $n$ are coprime. I have therefore determined the elements of $\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ to be:

$$\phi_k(\zeta)=\zeta^k \ \ \ \ \ \ \  k=1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23.$$
And I know that these elements determine the whole group since $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=|\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})|=8.$ I also know that this Galois group will be isomorphic to a product of cyclic groups of prime power order, and I believe this to be $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}2$ but am not exactly sure how to show this. I know that once I've shown this I can determine the subgroups of $\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ by examining the subgroups of the isomorphic product of cyclic groups (the one I believe to be $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}4\times\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}2$). I am unsure how to then determine their corresponding fixed fields, can anyone give me guidance?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I have determined the isomorphic group to actually be $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ by the following.
$\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian and of order 8. Thus it is isomorphic to one of: $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. We have that $\phi_k^2=\phi_1=id$ for $k=1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23$ and thus every non identity element has order 2, meaning we have isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. How do I proceed?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has $16$ elements.  However, since the Galois group is abelian and  of order $8$, there are only $2$ possibilities for it.

Comment: @KajHansen You mean $3$ possibilities...

Comment: Apologies for the typo, I meant $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, I have edited the original post.

Comment: Oops, yes @peterag.  Forgot about $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$.

Comment: I have found the isomorphic group to be $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ as can be seen in the updated post. I am still unsure how to proceed. I know I can now find the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ and relate this back to the galois group, but I'm unsure how to identify the elements of the galois group with the elements of $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: It depends how explicit you need to be. If $K = \mathbb Q ( \zeta_{24})$, the sub-fields are of the form  $K^H$, where $H$ runs through the subgroups of the Galois group, courtesy of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. So if you don't need to describe  $K^H$ further, 'all' you need to do  is write down the lattice of subgroups $H$, and write the (opposite) lattice of subfields $K^H$, without any  'explicit' description of $K^H$. Do you figure that's good enough?

Comment: There will be seven subgroups of order two (generated by a choice of non-neutral element). If you think of $\Bbb{Z}_2^3$ as a 3-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ these 7 subgroups are the 1-dim subspaces. There will also be seven 2-dim subspaces, i.e. 7 subgroups of order four. So a total of fourteen intermediate fields. The order four subgroups have quadratic intermediate fields, each of the form $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt n)$ for some integer $n$. Locating those seven may sound like work, but if you remember the real/imaginary parts of 3rd, 4th and 8th roots of unity, you'll do fine!

Comment: @peterag I am fine with the Galois correspondence and drawing the lattice in an abstract sense, its the explicit determination of the fixed fields where I am struggling. The question asks:
a) Determine the lattice subgroups of $H<G=\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ in terms of your chosen generators.
b) For each of these subgroups $H$ determine its corresponding fixed field $F=H^{\dagger}, \ \mathbb{Q}\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, and express each $F$ in the form $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_r)$ for appropriate $r$ and $\mu_i$.

Comment: I have done part a), choosing $\phi_5$, $\phi_{13}$ and $\phi_{23}$ as my generators. I just don't know how to now determine the fixed fields explicitly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have done part a) and got my lattice of subgroups of $G=\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q})$ but I am still struggling to understand how to do part b). Is there any more hints you can give me?